# How to get an Serverside Value to the phonegap parameters

Tags: cordova, xpages

Has anyone any idea how to get a documentUNID into the function of the file transfer from phonegap?

I've tryed some solutions but nothing seems to work:

First I tried:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="file";
  options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

  var params = new Object();
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.id = XSP.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").value

  options.params = params;

  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  ft.upload(imageURI, "serverURL", win, fail, options);
}
```

This results in 'function could not be found'.

My second ides was to compute the documentID by using `Document1.getDocument.getUniversalID()`

This also results in 'function could not be found'.

has annyone any idea how to get a Serverside value to the paramters of this phonegap function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add brackets to the getDocument portion also so that it reads `Document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()`. This might resolve the issue you had.